# How can I use imagemagick to create a regular, single-paged pdf from a series of jpeg images that would span over two pages?

Tags: image, pdf, imagemagick

As the title suggests: I have a series of ordered JPEG images. Each of those is supposed to span over a double page in a magazine-style layout. How can I create a print-ready pdf from those JPEGs using ImageMagick? I suppose, this would involve splitting the JPEGs into to halves each and then simply storing them one after another?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: There is no code yet.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Can you post an example image of what you want? If I understand, you would need to split the images in half and for each page append all the half images vertically. See -append at https://imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/#append_array. But why would you want to split an image over two pages in a PDF?

Comment: I hope this works... This is the sketch of one image: https://ibb.co/6PT6VpV 
It's 1 JPEG file that contains two pages of a magazine (i.e. a double page, width: 1750 pixels, height: 1000 pixels). But there is not only this image, but more than 100 such images. They need to be split into two halves, and then all these halves need to be appended(?) into a pdf file where one "half" corresponds to one page.